# Is the minimal number of colors needed to color a graph some fixed number?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Consider to following decision problem:

> **Input**: Undirected graph $G=(V,E)$
>
> **Question**: Is the minimum numbers of colors needed to color the vertices  (such that every two adjacent vertices aren't colored the same) **exactly** 2015?

Note that 2015 could be any fixed number. This number is not part of the input.

I need to understand what is the minimal complexity class that contain this problem, between $\sf P,NP,coNP,NP\cup coNP,\Sigma _{2} \cap \Pi _{2}, \Sigma _{2} \cup \Pi _{2}$.

I don't it's $\sf NP$ or $\sf coNP$ since I can't think of a verifier for both the language or it's complement. The problem is maybe in $\sf \Sigma _{2} \cap \Pi {2}$ since we can think of it as

> **exists** $f$ some 2009-coloring function, **for-all** $g$, 2008-coloring function, $f$ is a correct coloring and $g$ isn't a correct coloring.

So by the above, it seems that the language is in $\sf \Sigma _{2}$, but the quantifiers order doesn't really matter here, so the language is also in $\sf \Pi _{2}$, I think.

And maybe the there is some deterministic polynomial-time algorithm?

Comment: That problem is in [DP](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37287/definition-of-dp). ​ ​

Answer (score 3):

The problem is always in $\Delta_2 = \Sigma_2 \cap \Pi_2$, as you mention. For some values of 2015 it is easier: deciding whether a graph has chromatic number 3 is NP-complete, and deciding whether a graph has chromatic number 2 or 1 is in P (since you can check whether a graph is bipartite in polytime).

Since deciding whether a graph has chromatic number 3 is NP-hard, so is deciding whether it has chromatic number 2015, by reduction: add a clique of size 2012, and connect it to all vertices; this increases the chromatic number by exactly 2012. So there is no hope for a polynomial time algorithm.